# How to create getAllNames that will return String with all user names in another class

Tags: java, class, oop

Here are my tasks

> you need to create array of users and print there names.

Then you need to create one more class UsersStorage, move mentioned above array of users to this class, so you will keep this array inside class.

Realize in this class method getFirstUserName that will return name of first user and getAllNames that will return String with all user names.

and my code

```
    package com.company;

public class Lesson4OOP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"Adam","Sara", "Mike" , "David"};
        int[] ages = {21, 25, 34, 16};
        UserStorage[] users = new UserStorage[names.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<users.length; i++){
            UserStorage u = new UserStorage();
            u.setName(names[i]);
            users[i] = u;
            u.setAllNames(names);
        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int j = 0; j<ages.length; j++){
            users[j].setAge(ages[j]);
        }
        System.out.print(users[2].getName());
        System.out.println(" is " + users[3].getAge() + " years old");
        System.out.print(names.getAllNames());

    }
}


    package com.company;

public class UserStorage {
    String nam;
    int ages;
    static String[] names = {"Adam","Sara", "Mike" , "David"};
    String separator = "";

    public void setName(String val){
        nam = val;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return nam;
    }
    public void setAge(int num){
        ages = num;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return ages;
    }
    public static void setAllNames(String[] getN){
        names = getN;
    }
    public String[] getAllNames(){
        for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
            System.out.print(separator + names[i]);
            separator = ", ";
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

Where are the mistakes? Because the output is 
Error:(21, 31) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAllNames()
  location: variable names of type java.lang.String[]

Comment: you are calling `names.getAllNames()` on String array name, and not on UserStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want call a method in a class not static ,create instance of that class and access the method .Second point is code is not correct way how you should write OO CODE.

```
UserStorage u = new UserStorage();
 u.getAllNames();
```

[Link](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6029486) for your reference